# На Ангарском и Грушевском перевалах, согласование верное?

Tags: согласование

На Ангарском и Грушевском перевалах, согласование верное?

Answer (score 3):

На Ангарском и Грушевском **перевалах.**

Имя существительное ставится в форме множественного числа, если подчеркивается **наличие нескольких предметов**, например:  встречи с болгарской и польской футбольными командами; участники гражданской и Великой Отечественной войн.

[XLIV. СОГЛАСОВАНИЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЙ И ПРИЛОЖЕНИЙ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)

Можно также учесть, что **согласование по смыслу**, то есть во мн.числе, является в современном языке приоритетным, его можно выбирать, когда есть сомнения при выборе варианта.